# How do I print multiple pages from WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Although there are some tutorials on web, I'm still lost on why this doesn't print multiple pages correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void printTest()
{
   PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
   PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();

   printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
   printDocument1.PrintPage += 
       new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

   DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       printDocument1.Print();
   }       
}

static void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
   SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

   Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);

   e.PageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 850, 1100);

   float pageWidth = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
   float pageHeight = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;

   float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
   int startX = 40;
   int startY = 30;
   int offsetY = 40;

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {             
       graphic.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY + offsetY);
       offsetY += (int)fontHeight;

       if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
       {
           e.HasMorePages = true;
           offsetY = 0;
       }
       else {
           e.HasMorePages = false;
       }
   }
}
```

You can find an example of this code's printed result here: [Printed Document](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3AbXJ0xsx1TNmYwMmUyZGItZWI0OS00ZDM0LTk4MmUtODJjNDc1MWEzY2Ez)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You never return from the loop. Change it to:

```cs
if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
{
    e.HasMorePages = true;
    offsetY = 0;
    return; // you need to return, then it will go into this function again
}
else {
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

In addition you need to change the loop to start at the current number on the 2nd page instead of restarting with i=0 again.

Comment: Yes, this works.
One question tho: whenever HasMorePages triggers flag, whole function PrintPage will run again from the begining?

Comment: e.HasMorePages is evaluated after the function returns (not when it's set). If it's true, it calls the function again. If it's false, it doesn't and stops printing.

Comment: I have extended my program now, but I'm stuck again, probably because of the same reason. Should I ask here or open new question?

Comment: Where are you stuck? If closely related, go ahead here. I can't judge that.

Comment: Did you guys ever get this solved. I am trying to do something similar.