# Print multiple pages in WinForms doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Coming from [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341284/how-do-i-print-multiple-pages-from-winforms)

which was answered really quick, I have stumbled upon upgraded problem.

I have changed my program to fill some DataSet from DB.

I call `Print()` on `printDocument`, everything works, it just doesn't want to register my `e.HasMorePages = true;`

Here is code:

```
   public static void printDokument()
   {
       if (result == DialogResult.OK)
       {

           DbDataPostavke = checkDB("SELECT * FROM " + tipDokumenta + "_postavke WHERE ID_" + tipDokumenta + " = " + stDokumenta);

           list = DbDataPostavke.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();                             
           printDocument.Print();
       }       
   }

   static void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
       graphic = e.Graphics;

       e.PageSettings.PaperSize = ps;

       stranSirina = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
       stranVisina = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;

       fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

       //this works/prints
       printDocument_PrintHeader();

       //this works/prints
       printDocument_PrintDocumentInfo();

       if (firstPage) printDocument_PrintSupplierInfo();    

       //Lines that I take from DB, amount of this lines is variable //it only prints one page, then it stops printing
       printDocument_PrintProductLines(e);

       //Sum of lines
       if(zadnjaStran) printDocument_printSum();

       //prints comment on document
       if (zadnjaStran) printDocument_PrintComment();

       //footer
       printDocument_PrintFooter();
   }

   static void printDocument_PrintProductLines(PrintPageEventArgs e)
   {
       //I print some stuff here (header, etc..) 

       String stranArtikliVrstica = String.Empty; // string for one line of data
       DataRow dataRow1 = null;
       DataRow dr = null;

       for(int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
       {
           dr = list[i];
           dataRow1 = poglejBazo("SELECT ime, EM, opis FROM Sifrant WHERE ID = " + dr[2].ToString()).Tables[0].Rows[0];

           stranArtikliVrstica = String.Format("{0,-38}  {1,10}  {2,5}  {3,9:C}  {4,9:C}", dataRow1[0].ToString() + " - " + dataRow1[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dataRow1[1].ToString(), dr[4], Convert.ToInt16(dr[3]) * Convert.ToInt16(dr[4]));

           list.Remove(dr);

           graphic.DrawString(stranArtikliVrstica, font, brush, startX + offsetX, startY + offsetY);
           offsetY += (int)font.GetHeight();

           //if there is less then 35 "lines" remaining, we have enough space for printing some other stuff, otherwise, that stuff doesn't print..
           if (list.Count() < 35) zadnjaStran = true;
           else zadnjaStran = false;

           if (offsetY > stranVisina - 50)
           {
               prvaStran = false;
               stevecStrani++;
               offsetY = 0;
               e.HasMorePages = true;
               return;
           }
       }

   }
```

So, when I try to print a document with a single page, everything works, but if I try to print a document with multiple pages, only the first page prints (Header, DocumentInfo, SupplierInfo, ProductLines (around 38 lines out of 80), Footer) and then there is no more pages (I'm testing with printing into PDF file..)

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a problem with e parameter in `PrintProductLines`? How can I tell function `PrintProductLines` that I want to trigger `HasMorePages` on e from original function? I know I can pass it by reference, but ref keyword doesn't work in my case :S

EDIT:

Changing `static void printDocument_PrintProductLines(ref PrintPageEventArgs e)` and   `printDocument_PrintProductLines(ref e);` throws an error:

> Error 2 Argument 1 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
>   Error 1 The best overloaded method match for
>   'GZIG.globalClass.printDocument_PrintPostavke(ref
>   System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Comment: You have to set e.HasMorePages to true in the PrintPage event handler to get more than a single page.

Comment: I have moved whole PrintArticleLines(e) procedure back into PrintPage function and still doesnt work. I'm setting HasMorePages on right e this time and it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be placing printing code like this into a static global class.

This routine belongs in the actual instance of the class that will be using the Graphics object.

```
private const int PAD = 4;
private int m_Line, m_LinesToPrint;
private Font m_Font;
private PrintDocument m_Doc;

private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (var dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog()) {
    if (m_Doc == null) {
      throw new NullReferenceException("Create the document before trying to print it.");
    }
    dlg.Document = m_Doc;
    m_Line = 0;
    m_LinesToPrint = list.Count;
    m_Font = new Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    dlg.ShowDialog();
  }
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  float lineHeight = m_Font.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + PAD;
  float yLineTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;
  for ( ; m_Line < m_LinesToPrint; m_Line++) {
    if (e.MarginBounds.Bottom < (yLineTop + lineHeight)) {
      e.HasMorePages = true;
      return;
    }
    DataRow dr = list[m_Line];
    DataRow row1 = poglejBazo("SELECT ime, EM, opis FROM Sifrant WHERE ID = " + dr[2].ToString()).Tables[0].Rows[0];
    string strText = String.Format("{0,-38}  {1,10}  {2,5}  {3,9:C}  {4,9:C}", dataRow1[0].ToString() + " - " + dataRow1[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dataRow1[1].ToString(), dr[4], Convert.ToInt16(dr[3]) * Convert.ToInt16(dr[4]));
    // list.Remove(list[m_Line]) <= DO NOT DO THAT!
    e.Graphics.DrawString(strText, m_Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(e.MarginBounds.Left, yLineTop));
    yLineTop += lineHeight;
  }
  e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks jp2code.  I have been struggling with printing multiple pages. I have also been staring at your code wondering why the for loop doesn't reset to "0" after the e.HasMorePages = true; & "return".  I finally saw what you did - you removed the int m_Line = 0 from the for loop! i.e., for ( ; m_Line < m_LinesToPrint; m_Lines++).  This meant you have to define m_Line globally.  Once I realized this my code started working!  Many thanks!

Comment: I hope I didn't cause you too much grief, Bob. I put the `int m_Line` global so that after calling the print method, I could read my variable and make sure all pages printed.