# Printing multiple document in c# window application

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, system.drawing

In c# window application I having a trouble with printing documents, when its become more than 1 page. See the following code which I am using for printing document and its working fine, while there is a small document i.e only one page.

On print button's click event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        pd.Document = doc;
        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
        DialogResult res = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.Print();
        }
    }
```

And PrintPageEventHandler is as following.

```
    void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
    //Fetching data from DB

        BillingApplicationEntities ent = new BillingApplicationEntities();
        List<tbCustBill> BillData = ent.tbCustBills.Where(s => s.BillId == 20133).ToList();

   //Printing doc

        Graphics grp = e.Graphics;

        Font fnt = new Font("Courier New", 12);
        float fontH = fnt.GetHeight();

        int startX = 10;
        int StartY = 10;
        int offset = 40;
        foreach (tbCustWorkDet d in WorkData)
        {
            string Pare = d.WorkName.PadRight(30);
            string pp = string.Format("{0:c}", d.Price).PadRight(30);

            string pl = Pare + pp;

            grp.DrawString(pl, fnt, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, StartY + offset);

            offset += (int)fontH + 5;
           if (offsetY >= pageHeight)
           {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                offsetY = 0;
                return; // you need to return, then it will go into this function again
           }
           else {
                 e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        }
        offset += 20;
        // And cont with other data to print
    }
```

This method is working fine and gives me my required o/p, but when data becomes more larger and its need more pages to print then in o/p it gives me only one page.

As I think for multiple pages we have to set following property to true

```
    e.HasMorePages = true;
```

But I don't know where and how to put this value...

In short I want to know how can I print multiple documents from above code?

In this code `return` will return to the function and entire execution start again, and so on this will become in Infinite loop. Please tell me how can I prevent with this problem.

Comment: Check this SO Post: [How do I print multiple pages from WinForms?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341284/how-do-i-print-multiple-pages-from-winforms

Comment: Try it.... may work.....>by the end of Print page event ---> add e.HasMorePages = m_currentPageOnPrint < (m_printToPage); give current page on print and printtopage as int pagenumbers

Comment: You are incrementing the variable `offset`, but testing the variable `offsetY`. It's a good idea to always declare variables. You can ensure this by setting Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, VB Defaults, Option Explicit to "on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `e.HasMorePages = true;` in the printpage handler, if there are more pages to print. This causes the handler to be called again. It is up to the handler to output the proper page.