# HasMorePages is not working. Setting the bit results in printing all the items on the same page

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

When I try to print preview with the code below, it prints the items over the previous printed items. When I put the `if` block outside of the `for` loop, it begins to generate an infinite page.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{    
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 40;
    int startY = 30;
    int lineperpage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY);
        startY += font.Height;
        lineperpage++;

        if (lineperpage > 50)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            startY = 30;
            lineperpage = 0;
            startX = 300;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: every time you have a new page, you set startY back to 30. that will print over the previous page will it not?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @agrothe: no he then goes 270 px to the right which should print it next the the previous prints

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print multiple pages from WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341284/how-do-i-print-multiple-pages-from-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the *data* you want to be printen and the actual drawing of a single page. You can't have them in the same method. Setting HasMorePages to true only signals to the PrintMangager to raise the `PrintPage` event again.

In your case it looks like your `i` variable is the data. You need to keep track 
of its progress outside of the PrintPage event.

```
int i = 0;  // keep track of data in an instance variable 

// this event is re-entrant. It will be called as long as HasMorePages = true;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{    
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
    int startX = 40;
    int startY = 30;
    int lineperpage = 0;

    // removed
    //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    // print a page as long as their is space left AND data available
    while (lineperpage < 50 && i < 100)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Line: " + i, font, brush, startX, startY);
        startY += font.Height;
        lineperpage++;

        i++;  // next dataitem
    }

    e.HasMorePages = i < 100; // keep printing as long as there is date 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```