# How To print a long string into multiple pages in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print a very long string using code below but it prints the whole text only in one page. Is there any easy way to print it correctly?

```
string text="the text has like 1000 words";

System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument p = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
    e1.Graphics.DrawString(text, new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 12), new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), new System.Drawing.RectangleF(50, 50, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - 50, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - 50));

};
try
{
    p.Print();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
}
```

I tried to solve it with [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341284/how-do-i-print-multiple-pages-from-winforms) but the method stuck in some loop that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print multiple pages from WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341284/how-do-i-print-multiple-pages-from-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that `PrintDocument` will raise the event `PrintPage` as long as *you* tell it there are more pages. It is your task to keep track of what is printed, what needs to printed next and if you need another page or not.

There are several ways to accomplish that. I have chosen in this case to take the content of your `text`, check how much of it fits on the current page, DrawString that bit and then update my processing string, called `remainingtext` to be able to repeat for the next Page. The decision if a next page is needed is controlled by setting `HasMorepages` of the PrintEvent arguments instance to true or false when we're done.

Here is the code:

```
PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();

var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
var margins = p.DefaultPageSettings.Margins;
var layoutArea = new RectangleF(
    margins.Left, 
    margins.Top, 
    p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - (margins.Left + margins.Right ), 
    p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - (margins.Top + margins.Bottom));
var layoutSize = layoutArea.Size;
layoutSize.Height = layoutSize.Height - font.GetHeight(); // keep lastline visible
var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

// what still needs to be printed
var remainingText = text;

p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
    int charsFitted, linesFilled;

    // measure how many characters will fit of the remaining text
    var realsize = e1.Graphics.MeasureString(
        remainingText, 
        font, 
        layoutSize, 
        StringFormat.GenericDefault, 
        out charsFitted,  // this will return what we need
        out linesFilled);

    // take from the remainingText what we're going to print on this page
    var fitsOnPage = remainingText.Substring(0, charsFitted);
    // keep what is not printed on this page 
    remainingText = remainingText.Substring(charsFitted).Trim();

    // print what fits on the page
    e1.Graphics.DrawString(
        fitsOnPage, 
        font, 
        brush, 
        layoutArea);

    // if there is still text left, tell the PrintDocument it needs to call 
    // PrintPage again.
    e1.HasMorePages = remainingText.Length > 0;
};
p.Print();
```

When I hookup an PrintPreviewControl this is the result:

[image: shows the printpage in action]

Comment: @user:578411 Hi rene, thanks for your clear and great answer. It works perfectly.The only problem is when the text is too long printings doesn't care about the bottom margins. How can I solve this?[link](http://imgur.com/a/1uek9)

Comment: I substracted the font.GetHeight from the layoutSize.Height. that works in my   solution. i've adapted the code to show how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to rene I figured it out how to print it correctly. I edit his code and the difference here is that the user chooses the paper size and rectangel drawing happens with choosen paper margin size. This is a ready printing method in case you want to use it...

```
private void Print(string thetext){


            try
            {

                System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument p = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

                var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12); 
                var brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);

                // what still needs to be printed
                var remainingText = theText;

                p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e1)
                {
                    int charsFitted, linesFilled;

                // measure how many characters will fit of the remaining text

                var realsize = e1.Graphics.MeasureString(
                        remainingText,
                        font,
                        e1.MarginBounds.Size, 
                        System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericDefault,
                        out charsFitted,  // this will return what we need
                        out linesFilled);

                // take from the remainingText what we're going to print on this page
                var fitsOnPage = remainingText.Substring(0, charsFitted);
                // keep what is not printed on this page 
                remainingText = remainingText.Substring(charsFitted).Trim();

                // print what fits on the page
                e1.Graphics.DrawString(
                        fitsOnPage,
                        font,
                        brush,
                        e1.MarginBounds); 

                    // if there is still text left, tell the PrintDocument it needs to call 
                    // PrintPage again.
                    e1.HasMorePages = remainingText.Length > 0;
                };

                System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pd = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();  
                pd.Document = p; 
                DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();

                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    p.Print();
                } 


            }catch(Exception e2)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e2.Message, "Unable to print",MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Code snippet for "when user clicked 'btnPrint' button, print 'rtbEditor' rich textbox's text.":

```
        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            var d = new PrintDialog();
            d.Document = new PrintDocument();
            d.Document.PrintPage += Dd_PrintPage;
            remainingText = rtbEditor.Text;
            var res = d.ShowDialog();
            try { if (res == DialogResult.OK) d.Document.Print(); }
            catch { }
        }

        string remainingText;
        private void Dd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e){

            //this code was for 1 page
            //e.Graphics.DrawString(rtbEditor.Text,new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12f),Brushes.Black,new PointF(10,10));

            //this is for multiple pages
            PrintDocument p = ((PrintDocument)sender);
            var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
            var margins = p.DefaultPageSettings.Margins;
            var layoutArea = new RectangleF(
                margins.Left,
                margins.Top,
                p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - (margins.Left + margins.Right),
                p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - (margins.Top + margins.Bottom));
            var layoutSize = layoutArea.Size;
            layoutSize.Height = layoutSize.Height - font.GetHeight(); // keep lastline visible
            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            int charsFitted, linesFilled;

            // measure how many characters will fit of the remaining text
            var realsize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(
                remainingText,
                font,
                layoutSize,
                StringFormat.GenericDefault,
                out charsFitted,  // this will return what we need
                out linesFilled);
            // take from the remainingText what we're going to print on this page
            var fitsOnPage = remainingText.Substring(0, charsFitted);
            // keep what is not printed on this page 
            remainingText = remainingText.Substring(charsFitted).Trim();

            // print what fits on the page
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                fitsOnPage,
                font,           
                brush,
                layoutArea);

            // if there is still text left, tell the PrintDocument it needs to call 
            // PrintPage again.
            e.HasMorePages = remainingText.Length > 0;
        }
```